# spring + tomcat + axis2 == jax-ws web service?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, tomcat, axis

I'm looking for a straightforward example / tutorial for implementing a JAX-WS (soap1.1 and soap1.2) web service based on wsdl definition using spring, axis2 and tomcat.

hint anyone ?

-- Yonatan

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as "straightforward" in the world of SOAP. Any example and tutorial is bound to be complex due to the overengineered nature of this beast.

If you can choose your technologies, I'd recommend putting axis aside, and using Tomcat 6 + Java 6 + Metro. [Metro](https://metro.dev.java.net/) is Sun's latest, greatest Java web services  (jax-ws) stack. Coupled with JavaEE annotations, it's a ***relatively*** painless way to get a web service off the ground quickly.

Sorry to not answer the question directly.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, even the latest version of Metro has issues with tomcat and JDK6 
I tried running the sample app on my machine and documented few issues I faced and resolved. 
For others benefit please check here : 
[Running Metro + Tomcat 6 + JDK 6](http://software-wikipedia.blogspot.com/2010/01/trying-to-run-jax-ws-sample-application.html)

Answer (score 1):

The NetBeans IDE is good place to start. Enable the Axis2 Support in NB plug-ins. You can create a JAX-WS based Web Service from the WSDL (assuming you are using contract first) and the JAX-WS based WS client too. If you dont like what NetBeans generates or its deployment strategy, you can still build upon the code that it has generated

Answer (score 1):

Axis2 does not support Spring web services when using Jax-WS. See this mailing list post:

http://markmail.org/message/hohdmsupo3r3gltl?q=list:org%2Eapache%2Ews%2Eaxis-user+spring+jax-ws

To do this you will need a custom module to add a BeanFactory into the MessageContext and then retrieve it out in your web service. Or you might write a custom dispatcher.